# Parsing Proguard Dump file

Tags: java, android, proguard

To find out if some important functions were removed (and without doing a lot of testing) I want to go through the Proguard Dump file. However, it is barely readable - are there any tools that can parse it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the developer docs, Proguard produces a file named 'usage.txt' which *'Lists the code that was stripped from the .apk'*. Wouldn't this file be of more use to you for finding out what's been removed?

See [ProGuard](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html)